# Bamboo stuck at validating Jira server

Tags: jira, bamboo, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

Im trying to configure Zephyr Add-on - "Zephyr for JIRA Test Management Add-on for Bamboo" as a build task in Bamboo, but it stuck at validating the Jira server.
The link between Bamboo and Jira is defined, the value of api calls in jira setting is set to on.

Comment: Anything related in the server logs from that time?

Comment: What is the network configuration? Are the servers on the same network? Is there any firewall between them? Did you get any errors when establishing the application link?

Comment: The link seems fine, they are on the same network and no errors. I will check the firewall issue, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in Zephyr. We are from Zephyr Support and the issue that you are facing seems can be handled well if you can raise a ticket with us and if we can go over a call or screen share meeting.
Please sign up to our support site "https://support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us" using your company email id and use the option "Submit a Case" to raise a ticket with us and one of our support engineers would immediately contact you. It's a better channel to keep track of Zephyr issues.

Let us know if you are facing any difficulty in raising the ticket and we can raise it on behalf of you.